# Using tiptap as text editor in my vue app. How do i download the content as pdf?

Tags: vue.js, tiptap

I use tiptap as a text editor tool in my vue app. I want to provide a button to download content thats in the editor as pdf. I am not sure if this is possible as there isnt a documentation on downloading as pdf or any other extension. Any suggestions?