# How to export TipTap documents as PDFs?

Tags: javascript, pdf, pdf-generation, rich-text-editor, tiptap

We're using TipTap to allow users to create and edit documents on our application, and one common ask is for save/export to pdf functionality.

Looking around online it seems like there's no consensus on how to do this. This question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71470748/using-tiptap-as-text-editor-in-my-vue-app-how-do-i-download-the-content-as-pdf) is effectively the same as mine (we use React but it should be similar enough) but it has no responses. This [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/tiptap-to-pdf?file=README.md) has a hacky way of doing this (I've also seen this method referenced in other responses) by first converting the editors content to a `canvas` (via html2canvas), then saving that Canvas as a PDF with `jspdf`. This doesn't really work for us since it creates massive document sizes. A 9 page document is almost 100mb with this method.

I'm thinking about trying to do this manually using JavaScripts `window.print()` function, or using something like puppeteer in my backend to attempt a print, but I'm not sure if these will work. Is there any better solution to this? Open to any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I recently implemented a download as pdf button in my tiptap editor in NextJs. It was using puppeteer on the backend, and applying the html from the document to be TipTap downloaded:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.setContent(fullHtml, { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' });
const pdfBuffer = await page.pdf({ format: 'A4' });
await browser.close();
const response = new NextResponse(pdfBuffer);
```

Ensure that if you have options for the user to style the document in css, you include that in the fullHtml variable. Note that I have not extensively tested this on longer documents.